# Draw a dynamic table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, subquery

Good morning, I'm trying to draw a dynamic table with some data, this query, draw a table that has a day, his week, and some data that I want to calculate dynamically.

This is my query

```
use Alfri
;with monthDates

as
(
    select  DATEADD(month, 0, CONVERT(DATE,'2013-09-09',102)) as d
            ,DATEPART(week, DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, '2013-09-09'),0)) as w,
            (
              SELECT SUM(
                          CASE WHEN arrive_yard IS NOT NULL THEN 
                                     DATEDIFF(mi, Solicitado, Libre)-DATEDIFF(mi, arrive_yard, leave_yard) 
                                ELSE 
                                     DATEDIFF(mi, Solicitado, Libre) 
                           END
                        ) as Tiempo 
              FROM MovimientoHoras 
              WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Solicitado, 102) = '2013-10-11'
            ) as info
    union all
    select  DATEADD(day, 1, d)
            ,DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, 1, d))
            , info
    from monthDates
    where d < DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, '2013-10-09')+1,-1)
)

SELECT * FROM monthDates
```

This query draw me a table like this.

```
d          |w     |info |
2013-09-09 | 36   | 2780|
2013-09-10 | 37   | 2780|
2013-09-11 | 37   | 2780|
2013-09-12 | 37   | 2780|
2013-09-13 | 37   | 2780|
2013-09-14 | 37   | 2780|
2013-09-15 | 37   | 2780|
2013-09-16 | 37   | 2780|
```

But the info's column isn't calculling dynamically and this is my dilenma.

The point is that column d is calculated dynamically and that's the value that I want to use in info's column query, something like this `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Solicitado, 102) = d) as info` instead of `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Solicitado, 102) = '2013-10-11') as info` where D is the date changing in every row, the way that I'm trying it just giving me same data of `'2013-10-11'`

Something like a While to change a day in that subquery

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic approach is to separate the part that generates dates from the part that calculates the info for that date:

```
;with monthDates as (
    select
        cast('20130909' as date) as d,
        datepart(week, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, '2013-09-09'), 0)) as w
    union all
    select
        dateadd(day, 1, d),
        datepart(week, dateadd(day, 1, d))
    from 
        monthDates
    where 
        d < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, '2013-10-09') + 1, -1)
)
select
    m.d,
    m.w,
    sum(
         datediff(mi, Solicitado, Libre) 
         - case when arrive_yard is not null then 
               datediff(mi, arrive_yard, leave_yard)    
           else 0 end
    ) info
from
    monthDates m
        left outer join
    MovimientoHoras h
        on cast(Solicitado as date) = m.d
group by
    m.d,
    m.w
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f489/2)</kbd>**